# Create SQL Table with FK

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a table with a couple columns having the same FK constraint.  What is wrong with my syntax?  I'm receiving a msg 102, incorrect syntax error around "fk_fighterID"

"FIGHTERS" is a table that has been set up with "fighterID" as the primarykey

```
CREATE TABLE FIGHTS
(
FIGHTID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
CONSTRAINT fk_fighterID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FIGHTERS(fighterID),
FIGHTER_ID_CHALLANGER int fk_fighterID,
FIGHTER_ID_CHALLANGED int fk_fighterID, 
CONSTRAINT fk_weightclass FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES WEIGHT_CLASSES 
      (classID)
WEIGHTCLASS NOT NULL fk_wightclass, 
IS_MAIN BIT NOT NULL,
IS_CO_MAIN BIT NOT NULL,
SCHEDULED ROUNDS TINYINT(1),
CONSTRAINT fk_WINMETH FOREIGN KEY (WINID) REFERENCES WINNING_METHODS (WINID)
WINNING METHOD NOT NULL fk_WINMETH
)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct Statement:** 

`CONSTRAINT fk_weightclass FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES WEIGHT_CLASSES (classID)`

**Incorrect Statement:**

`CONSTRAINT fk_fighterID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FIGHTERS(fighterID),`

You forgot to mention something like **'(classId)'**.

Edit: 
I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your above query is wrong, try below query if it makes sense.

`CREATE TABLE FIGHTS
(
  FIGHTID               INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FIGHTER_ID_CHALLANGER INT,
  FIGHTER_ID_CHALLANGED INT,
  IS_MAIN               BIT NOT NULL,
  IS_CO_MAIN            BIT NOT NULL,
  SCHEDULED_ROUNDS      TINYINT(1),
  WEIGHTCLASS           INT NOT NULL,
  CLASS_ID              INT NOT NULL,
  WINNING_METHOD        INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_fighterID FOREIGN KEY (FIGHTER_ID_CHALLANGER) REFERENCES FIGHTERS (fighterID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_weightclass FOREIGN KEY (CLASS_ID) REFERENCES WEIGHT_CLASSES (classID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_WINMETH FOREIGN KEY (WINNING_METHOD) REFERENCES WINNING_METHODS (WINID)
);`

Comment: I had it both ways as above, I have corrected it to the "correct statement" but still get the error

Comment: That gets me closer - My goal is to create the FK Constraint fk_fighterID such that I can use it on 2 columns.  The code above seems close but tells me that "Fighters" references an invalid table.

Comment: few more errors on my part - needed to reference PK.  also needed to match up data types.  i was able to get my table set up!  thanks

Comment: Great @JasonVondersmith

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn`t the constraints be outside of the table creation statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales.TempSalesReason (TempID int NOT NULL, Name nvarchar(50), 
CONSTRAINT PK_TempSales PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (TempID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_TempSales_SalesReason FOREIGN KEY (TempID) 
    REFERENCES Sales.SalesReason (SalesReasonID) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```